# CSS jQuery Scrollpane Issue

Tags: jquery, css

I am using jquery.jscrollpane.js to put scroll bar on divs. It seems to be putting a horizontal scroll bar on the bottom of the following page, can anyone help please?

http://souk.gumpshen.com/our-story/

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with your css on `.flower`.

```
.flower {
    background: transparent url("../images/flowers.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    margin-top: -360px;
    left: 696px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 101;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

You set the width too large so it's overflowing off of the page.  You can also change your height, since it's just using a background image of 289px x 367px and remove `width: 100%;`

```
.flower {
    background: transparent url("../images/flowers.png") no-repeat 0 0;
    margin-top: -360px;
    left: 696px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 101;
    width: 289px;
    height: 367px;
}
```

Comment: Tust tried you code but unfortunalty it didn't work. Any other ideas? Help is really appreciated.

Comment: It works for me with developer tools so long as the `.flower` doesn't touch the edge of my browser http://i.imgur.com/O696Q.jpg

Comment: I am looking at it in FireFox

Comment: Same result on firefox http://i.imgur.com/RdxTI.jpg  Can you make the change on the live site to confirm you're giving it the right styles?

Comment: Plugged in the ammended CSS to the live site still getting the same results. Thanks for the help with this BTW.

Comment: Well it looks good to me.  Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to accomplish?